# Is there a linguistic term the type of solecism of using "more X" when "Xer" is the established comparative?

Tags: comparatives, errors

So I posted a joke on Facebook, and one of the peanut gallery chimed in that where I'd used *vaster*, he would have preferred *more vast*.

Leaving aside the question of whether *vaster* itself is well-established enough, is there a linguistic term or at least well-understood heading under which errors in English comparatives are collected?

I'm talking specifically about the kinds of errors where non-native or less well-read native speakers use, e.g., *more hot* rather than *hotter*, or *more wet* rather than *wetter*. Really egregious cases.

I am not asking about cases where reasonable and well-educated people can legitimately disagree on whether "Xer" is well-established enough to displace "more X", or usage of "more X" is still broadly observed in the population.

Comment: Not specific to comparative errors but the general term for the errors where irregular forms are replaced with regular forms is *overregularization*. I'm not sure if there is a specific term for comparative errors. You might say "comparative overregularization". You can see a study here where the term *overregularization* is used for comparative errors: http://www.lingref.com/cpp/mcd/2009/paper2349.pdf

Comment: Yeah, overregularization is probably the most specific single word for this. It includes using -ed for all past tenses instead of strong forms ('bringed' instead of 'brought'). A single word just for errors in forming the comparative? Not likely.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is if the initial word has only one syllable, use the suffix; in all other cases, use "more."

Plus, if you add the suffix and the resulting word has two syllables, go ahead and use the suffix boldly: curvier, nuttier, etc.

There are a few exceptions, as well as jokes (which can also be viewed as exceptions, such as "curiouser and curiouser" (from Lewis Carroll's *Alice's Adventures and Romances*).

Comment: Thanks, +1, this is useful information, and new to me. But I'm more specifically looking for a term for the gaffe of misusing or overgeneralizing rules about comparatives. Is there one?

Comment: @DanBron: What do I know from rules. Language came first! One's intuition takes precedence! Except for the rule of thumb, of course. ... I'm weird like that, don't take me too seriously unless I insist you do.

Comment: @JEL: Don't kill me. // Furnishing some examples of 2-syllable words pertaining to this issue would be nice.// My spelling is very impressionistic; I don't know what I'd do without ELU's lightning-quick spellchecker.// "Curvier" may have three syllables formally, but it scans beautifully as a trochee.

Comment: Like Curvier and Ives, I suppose.

Comment: @JEL Redeemable gibberish?  Half right.  Or should I say half vast?

Comment: @deadrat: Curvier and Ives had easy lives.